# Assigning fields in an equals() method

Tags: java, equals, lazy-initialization

Suppose you have a written a class and have used lazy initialization to assign one of its fields. Suppose that the computation for that field only involves the other fields and is guaranteed to produce the same result every time. When two equal instances of the class encounter one another, it makes sense for them to share the value of the lazily initialized field (if either knows it). You could do this in the `equals()` method. Here is a class showing what I mean.

```
final class MyClass {

    private final int number;
    private String string;

    MyClass(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    String getString() {
        if (string == null) {
            string = OtherClass.expensiveCalculation(number);
        }
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this) { return true; }
        if (!(object instanceof MyClass)) { return false; }
        MyClass that = (MyClass) object;
        if (that.number != number) { return false; }
        String thatString = that.string;
        if (string == null && thatString != null) {
            string = thatString;
        } else if (thatString == null && string != null) {
            that.string = string;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return number; }
}
```

To me, this information-sharing seems the logical thing to do if you are going to go to the effort of lazily initializing a field, yet I have never seen an example of anyone using the `equals()` method in this way.

Is it a common or standard technique? If so, what is it called? If it is not a common technique, can I ask (at the risk of having the question put on hold as primarily opinion-based) what people think about it? Is it a good idea to use the `equals()` method to do anything other than check for equality?

Comment: If this really makes your application perform better in a significant way (when performance-tested with realistic production-like data in a way that is also production-like) then go for it. But be careful to document this well, preferably in the code, and to make sure that there are unit tests covering this behavior in every way; otherwise, the next person after you who has to maintain the code (or yourself in a few months time) is going to hate your guts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you describe is sometimes a good one, especially in situations where it is likely that many large immutable objects, despite being independently constructed, will end up being identical.  Because it is much faster to compare equal references than to compare large objects which happen to be equal, it may be advantageous to have code which compares two large-objects and finds them to be identical replace one of the references with a reference to the other.  For this to be workable, one should attempt to establish some sort of ordering among the objects in question to ensure that repeated comparisons will eventually yield the same canonical value.  This could be accomplished by having objects include a `long` sequence number and consistently replacing references to newer values with references to older-but-equal values, or by comparing the `identityHashCode` value of the equal references and discarding whichever one, if any, has the lower value (if two references which identify distinct but identical instances, happen to report the same `identityHashCode`, both should be kept).

A nasty but unfortunate wrinkle in this is that Java has very poor multi-threading support for *effectively-immutable* objects.  For an effectively-immutable object to be thread-safe, any access to an array or non-`final` field must go through a `final` field.  The cheapest way of accomplishing that is probably to have the object contain a `final` field into which it stores a reference to itself, and have all methods which access non-`final` fields do so through that `final` field, but that's a bit ugly.  Still, changing references distinct-but-identical references with references to the same object could offer some significant performance advantages despite the silly redundant `final` field accesses (since the target of the final field would be guaranteed to be in-cache, dereferencing it would be much cheaper than a normal dereference).

BTW, it would in many cases be possible to include an "equivalence-relation" mechanism such that once some objects were compared and found to be equal, discovering that any of them is equal to another object would cause all of them to be quickly recognizable as such.  I haven't figured out how to avoid the possibility of a deliberately-nasty-but-legitimate usage pattern causing a memory leak, however.

Answer (score 3):

This looks dangerous to me: the use of a side affect of a public method of Object to set an object's state. This will break if you subclass this class, and then override the subclass's equals method, a common thing to do. Just don't do this.

Comment: But is it really a side-effect? You're not changing anything that would affect how the instance is seen from outside. The class is effectively immutable. Also, you can't override `equals()` - I deliberately made the class final for that reason.

Comment: @pbabcdefp `You're not changing anything that would affect how the instance is seen from outside.` So, changing the value of `string` doesn't affect the returned value of `getString()`?

Comment: @Tom Read the code very, very carefully. You are setting the string, but the original  value of `null` would never have been returned by the `getString()` method anyway.

Answer (score 2):

"Suppose that the computation for that field only involves the other fields and is guaranteed to produce the same result every time."

Given this supposition, you can assert that the value of the lazily initialized field *does not matter* because if the values of the other fields are the same, the calculated value will also be the same.

**Edit**
I guess I sidestepped the original question, so I'll answer that too.  In the scenario you've created, there is nothing inherently wrong with what you're proposing.

The argument I would make is simply from a pragmatic standpoint: what happens when someone else is changing the definition of `getString()` (or more likely - changing the definition of the long running calculation that results in that value) and it starts relying on something that's not part of the object's equality considerations?

The reason conventional wisdom says that `equals()` should be side effect free is that most developers expect it to be side effect free.

Comment: As long as `expensiveComputation` returns the same result every time, the `equals` method is essentially side-effect free. I agree it's not great that `expensiveComputation` is defined in another class, but that was to make my example as simple as possible. If I were to actually do this (and you can all relax - I never have), I would put the code computing the `String` inside `MyClass` along with a comment indicating that any changes to the code mustn't change the fact that the result should only depend on the value of `number`.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but it's not a question of whether it's possible to make the cache operation (which is essentially what you're imitating here) safe. It's a question of how much it costs in terms of time and energy to write it that way, and then make sure no one ever changes it. At this point, I'd say the calculation would have to be phenomenally expensive to justify the amount of work that's required simply to not have to run it twice.

Comment: That's an argument against lazy-initialization, which is a very common technique. Some of the standard idioms involving lazy-initialization are just as complicated as this. The double-check idiom springs to mind.

Comment: I was arguing that the amount of work saved by assigning the value inside of `equals()` would have to be phenomenal before I'd consider it justifiable simply because of the weight carried by the default expectation that `equals()` didn't have side effects.

Comment: One danger with lazy initialization in Java is that its memory model offers no reasonable way to express the concept. Lazily initializing a primitive, or a reference to a new instance a class which qualifies as "immutable" under the memory model would be safe if code wouldn't be bothered by having the initialization be seen or not seen.  Lazily initializing a reference to a newly-created instance of a mutable type like an array, however, is *not* safe, even if the array will never be modified after it is exposed [I know of no hardware platform where a JVM implementation should have...

Comment: ...any trouble allowing code which writes a field to unilaterally express the necessary "has-before" relationship without requiring anything special of code which reads it [if the writer could ensure that it the contents of the a newly-created object would get published before a reference could become available to another thread, there should be no possible sequence of events where that other thread would see an incomplete object; unfortunately, the only way to ensure the field write gets sequenced after the creation of an object is to make the field `final`, precluding lazy initialization.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do this, for three reasons:

1. General software-engineering principles, such as cohesion, loose coupling, and "don't repeat yourself", militate against it: your `equals(...)` method will be doing something not very "equals"-y, that overlaps with the logic of your `getString()` method. Someone updating the logic of `getString()` might well fail to notice if they also need to update the logic of `equals(...)`. (You might think that the logic of `equals(...)` will continue to be correct no matter *how* `getString()` is changed — after all, you're just having `equals(...)` copy the reference from one object to an equivalent one, so presumably that should always stay the same? — but the problem is that complex systems evolve in ways that you can't always predict in advance. When a requirement changes, you don't want to have make random changes in parts of the code that aren't obviously related to the requirement.)
2. Thread-safety. Your `string` field currently isn't `volatile`, and your `getString()` method currently isn't `synchronized`, so there's no attempt at thread-safety here anyway; but if you were to make the rest of the class thread-safe, it would not be perfectly straightforward to change `equals(...)` to be thread-safe without risking deadlocks. (This overlaps a bit with point #1, but I'm listing it separately because #1 is solely about the difficulty of knowing *that you have to* change `equals(...)`, whereas this issue is a bit tricky to address even *given* that knowledge.)
3. Unlikelihood of usefulness. There's not much reason to expect it to happen very often that two instances get `equals(...)`-compared when one has already been lazy-initialized and the other has not; so the extra code complexity, and downsides mentioned above, are not likely to be worth it. (Remember: code is not free. In order to pass cost–benefit analysis, the benefits of a piece of code must exceed the costs of testing, understanding, maintaining, and supporting it in the future.) If it's worthwhile to share these lazy-initialized values between equivalent instances, then that should be done in a clearer and more-organized fashion that does not rely on happenstance. (For example, you might make the class's constructor private, and have a `static` factory-method that checks a `static` `WeakHashMap` for an existing instance before creating and returning a new one.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm in agreement about points 1 and 3 - the code isn't maintainable, and a `WeakHashMap` is clearly the sane route to caching. On point 2, I'm not so sure. I'm only on page 3 of Java Concurrency In Practice, so what I'm about to ask probably exposes total ignorance... but why does it matter if the variable `string` is not `volatile`? Surely all that means is that a value assigned to it by another thread may not be seen, possibly causing `expensiveCalculation()` to be executed unnecessarily at a later point. But that doesn't mean the class isn't thread-safe, or does it?

Comment: @pbabcdefp: Hmm, good question. The spec doesn't allow completely spurious writes to be perceived, so if thread #1 updates `string` from `null` to a non-null reference, then thread #2 could only see `null` or that reference; and the `String` class uses `final` internally to obtain the special guarantees that ensure that any thread that observes a non-null reference of type `String` will observe the fully-initialized `String` object. (See section 17.5 of the JLS.) I wrote that paragraph under the assumption that you wouldn't want `expensiveCalculation()` to be called multiple *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* times, but if you're actually O.K. with such duplicate calls, then yes, I think the existing code is thread-safe. (But I stand by that paragraph anyway. If you decided you wanted a stronger thread-safety guarantee, or if you changed that field to something other than `String` and so had to use a more-explicit thread-safety mechanism, or whatnot, it would be a bit tricky to keep `equals(...)` in line with that without risking deadlocks.)

Comment: You're completely right that I really didn't want multiple calls to `expensiveCalculation()`. The only reason I didn't use `volatile` and/or `synchronized` in my example is that I'm not confident about how to use them properly.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: In the absence of this logic in `equals()`, you can either just mark `getString()` as `synchronized`, or else mark `string` as `volatile` and use double-checked locking in `getString()`: `public String getString() { if (string == null) { synchronized(this) { if (string == null) { string = OtherClass.expensiveCalculation(number); } } } return string; }`. (The former approach is simpler, and may perform better if these objects are rarely shared across threads; the latter approach will perform better if these objects are frequently shared across threads, by reducing locking.)